# Validate form fields based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a situation where I need to be able to add dynamic rows for "additional information" that a user may want to enter, but I also need to validate those fields.

Currently, I have a javascript solution that dynamically adds rows when the user clicks a link (up to 8 additional rows).  No problem there.  This is the javascript that does it:

```
   function myFunction() {

       var table = document.getElementById("formtable");
       var rowNum = document.getElementById("formtable").rows.length - 1;
       var addNum = 1;
       var geFrmNextNumber = (((rowNum - addNum) * 2) + addNum + 9);

       var row = table.insertRow(-1);

       var dprimaryemailaddress = "'" + "dprimaryemailaddress" + rowNum + "'";
       var vprimaryemailaddress = "'" + "vprimaryemailaddress" + rowNum + "'";
       var rprimaryemailaddress = "'" + "rprimaryemailaddress" + rowNum + "'";
       var oprimaryemailaddress = "'" + "oprimaryemailaddress" + rowNum + "'";
       var dprimary_phone_number = "'" + "dprimary_phone_number" + rowNum + "'";
       var vprimary_phone_number = "'" + "vprimary_phone_number" + rowNum + "'";
       var rprimary_phone_number = "'" + "rprimary_phone_number" + rowNum + "'";
       var oprimary_phone_number = "'" + "oprimary_phone_number" + rowNum + "'";
       var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
           cell0.className = "input-wrapper";
       cell0.innerHTML = "<h4 class='hide-for-medium-up'></h4><input type='hidden' name="+dprimaryemailaddress+" value='Contact Type:'><select class='custom dropdown' name="+vprimaryemailaddress+" id="+vprimaryemailaddress+" required><option value='' selected>Select one</option><option value='Email address'> Email address </option><option value='Mobile number'> Mobile number </option></select><input type='hidden' name="+rprimaryemailaddress+" value='yes'><input type='hidden' name="+oprimaryemailaddress+" value="+geFrmNextNumber+"><small class='error empty'>Contact type is a required field.</small>";
           geFrmNextNumber = geFrmNextNumber + addNum;
       var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
           cell1.className = "input-wrapper";
       cell1.innerHTML = "<h4 class='hide-for-medium-up'>Primary Phone Number: </h4><input type='hidden' name="+dprimary_phone_number+" value='Primary Phone Number:' required><input type='text' name="+vprimary_phone_number+" size='45' id='primary_phone_number' maxlength='45'><input type='hidden' name="+rprimary_phone_number+" value='yes'><input type='hidden' name="+oprimary_phone_number+" value='"+geFrmNextNumber+"'>";
               geFrmNextNumber = geFrmNextNumber + addNum;
     }
```

This generates the following table elements in the browser, with code like this for the dropdown:

```
    <td class="input-wrapper">
    <h4 class="hide-for-medium-up"></h4>
    <input type="hidden" name="dprimaryemailaddress2" value="Contact Type:">
    <select class="custom dropdown" name="vprimaryemailaddress2" id="primaryemailaddress" required="">
    <option value="" selected="">Select one</option>
    <option value="Email"> Email address </option>
    <option value="SMS"> Mobile number </option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="rprimaryemailaddress2" value="no">
    <input type="hidden" name="oprimaryemailaddress2" value="12">
    <small class="error empty">Contact type is a required field.</small>
    </td>
```

and for the text field:

```
    <td class="input-wrapper">
    <h4 class="hide-for-medium-up"> Primary Phone Number: </h4>
    <input type="hidden" name="dprimary_phone_number2" value="Primary Phone Number:">
    <input type="text" name="vprimary_phone_number2" size="45" id="primary_phone_number" maxlength="45">
    <input type="hidden" name="rprimary_phone_number2" value="no">
    <input type="hidden" name="oprimary_phone_number2" value="13">
    </td>
```

As you can see, it adds a form field beside when it adds the select box each time a row is added.  Any select box displayed needs to be required, and so does it's corresponding text field.  That's the easy part.

The part I'm stuck on is that if the user selects email, I need to validate the input field for an email address, and if they select phone, I need to validate that the field is only numbers, and 10 digits long.

I have fumbled my way to something like this:

```
    $("#form").on("submit",function(ev) {
var Form = document.getElementById('formtable');         
for(I = 2; I < childs.length; I++) {                    
    format = document.getElementById("vprimaryemailaddress" + I).querySelector("option[selected]").value;
    if(format == "Email address"){

    }
```

But I am not convinced this is going to work, and I'm not sure how to finish it.  I'm hoping someone has either done this before, or knows how to do it.

Unfortunately, I'm forced to use something called GenForm (which is why some of the values have d, v, r, or o with them), and I'm stuck with strictly Javascript, and some jQuery.  Everything has to be client-side, and should work on mobile too.

Any suggestions?